# Access ancestors

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recursion

I have an Access db table, that holds couples of values: (SourceId, DestinationId). Both values are taken from the same list of Id's.
I want to create a list (query result?) of all item's ancestors. Ie, if the user enters Id=15, I'd like to return all Id's that are destinations for source-15, but also their destinations etc.
For example, if my table hold

```
15, 3 |
15, 4 |
4, 7 |
4, 8 |
3, 5 |
5, 2 |
1, 9
```

Id like to return 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2 (but not return 9).

I guess the solution should include some VBA code with loops or recursion, but I got confused by recordsets versus collections.

Any idea?
Thanks,
Aviram

Comment: is depth of ancestors fixed (e.g. parent-child-grandchild-grandgrandchild) or it's arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Access SQL lacks the CONNECT BY syntax that Oracle uses to do hierarchical queries. However, if you are prepared to create a temporary table you can emulate it in Access with a loop.
In this example your original table is "LinkTab" and the temporary table will be "TmpTree" an you are starting from SourceID 15.

First execute:

```
SELECT SourceID, DestID, 1 as Lvl INTO TmpTree FROM LinkTab WHERE SourceID = 15
```

Then in a loop, repeatedly execute:

```
INSERT INTO TmpTree ( SourceID, DestID, Lvl )
SELECT newrows.SourceID, newrows.DestID, TmpTree.Lvl + 1
FROM TmpTree INNER JOIN LinkTab newrows ON TmpTree.DestID = newrows.SourceID
WHERE TmpTree.Lvl = (SELECT MAX(Lvl) FROM TmpTree)
```

until the statement returns zero affected rows (or if you can't detect this, count the rows in TmpTree each time and stop when they don't increase)

Now your results can be retrieved with :

```
SELECT DestID FROM TmpTree
```

And finally, to tidy up:

```
DROP TABLE TmpTree
```

I've tested these statements in the Access Query designer and they get the desired result.